# Doesn't connect to localhost when running within a docker container using nodejs app & anguar

Tags: node.js, angular, docker

I am using Nodejs with **angular app**. I deploy angular to my docker desktop. It is running but when I want access from my pc using localhost from PC browser , it does not connect..

Here is docker image running

[image]

Here is Dockerfile code

```
    FROM node:16.13.1 as build
    WORKDIR /app
    COPY package.json /app
    COPY . .
    RUN npm install
    RUN npm run build --prod
    RUN ls -la dist
    FROM nginx:alpine
    COPY --from=build /app/dist /usr/share/nginx/html
    EXPOSE 4200
```

When I want access using **http://localhost:4200/** from my pc , it is not connecting.
Please help to find out the problem..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EXPOSE 4200 does nothing and is in this case misleading. You use EXPOSE to document what port the image listens on. As Antoine says, nginx listens on port 80, so if you want an EXPOSE statement, it should be `EXPOSE 80`.

Remove the EXPOSE statement since it's misleading

```
FROM node:16.13.1 as build
WORKDIR /app
COPY package.json /app
COPY . .
RUN npm install
RUN npm run build --prod
RUN ls -la dist
FROM nginx:alpine
COPY --from=build /app/dist /usr/share/nginx/html
```

When you run your container, you can then map port 80 in the container to port 4200 on your machine like this

```
docker run -d -p 4200:80 my_image_name
```

You'll then be able to load your app by going to http://localhost:4200/

Answer (score 0):

`nginx:alpine` expose on port 80.
port 4200 is used for development when you run `npm start` or `ng serve`.